# Trouble compiling cuda code

Tags: cuda, makefile

I want to compile [this volume rendering project](http://code.google.com/p/vfray/). I installed the CUDA toolkit and SDK on my Ubuntu 10.10 machine and have been able to run its examples, yet I'm getting this:

```
antonio@antonio-desktop:~/vfray$ make
make -f MakefileCPU
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/antonio/vfray'
make[1]: `vfRayCPU' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/antonio/vfray'
make -f MakefileCUDA
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/antonio/vfray'
nvcc  -o vfRay.cu_o -c vfRay.cu --ptxas-options=-v --compiler-bindir=/usr/bin/gcc-4.3 --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing   -I. -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/SDK/C/common/inc -DUNIX -O3 
/usr/bin/gcc-4.3: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [vfRay.cu_o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/antonio/vfray'
make: *** [cuda] Error 2
```

How can I fix this?

---

**Edit:** when running the steps described by talonmies on the vfRay.cu file I get:

```
  antonio@antonio-desktop:~/vfray$ nvcc --compiler-bindir=./jdir -arch=sm_20 -c -Xptxas="-v" vfRay.cu
    vfRay.cu:25: fatal error: cutil.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
```

**New Edit:** alright, when doing -L to include the cutil.h directory I got this for vfRay.cu and vfRayKernel.cu.

```
antonio@antonio-desktop:~/vfray$ nvcc --compiler-bindir=./jdir -arch=sm_20 -c -Xptxas="-v"  vfRay.cu -I/home/antonio/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc/
vfRay.cu:48: fatal error: vfRayKernel.cu: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
antonio@antonio-desktop:~/vfray$ nvcc --compiler-bindir=./jdir -arch=sm_20 -c -Xptxas="-v"  vfRayKernel.cu -I/home/antonio/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc/
vfRayKernel.cu(80): error: identifier "BLOCK_SIZE" is undefined

vfRayKernel.cu(181): error: identifier "BLOCK_SIZE" is undefined

vfRayKernel.cu(262): error: identifier "BLOCK_SIZE" is undefined

3 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000064a5_00000000-4_vfRayKernel.cpp1.ii".
```

I think this is a makefile problem, I doubt this compilation will work without modifying it.

This is the makefile for the project:

```
#
# Makefile CPU / CUDA
#

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

all:    cpu cuda

cpu:        MakefileCPU
            make -f MakefileCPU

cuda:       MakefileCUDA
            make -f MakefileCUDA

clean:
            make -f MakefileCPU clean
            make -f MakefileCUDA clean
```

I made this mod and isn't working:

```
all:    cpu cuda

cpu:    MakefileCPU
        make -f MakefileCPU

cuda:   MakefileCUDA
        make -f MakefileCUDA
        nvcc --compiler-bindir=./jdir -arch=sm_20 -c -Xptxas="-v"

clean:
        make -f MakefileCPU clean
        make -f MakefileCUDA clean
```

**Edit:** I modified the common.mk file so that line 93 points to the gcc 4.4, now I'm getting the cutil missing error. Where can I modify that? I tried placing it inside a ld folder in usr/bin, but ld is a program and I can't erase it.

antonio@antonio-desktop:~/vfray$ make

```
make -f MakefileCPU
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/antonio/vfray'
make[1]: `vfRayCPU' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/antonio/vfray'
make -f MakefileCUDA
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/antonio/vfray'
g++ -fPIC -o .///vfRay  .///vfRayPreComp.o  .///vfRay.cu_o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/usr/local/cuda/SDK/C/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/SDK/C/common/lib -lcudart -lGL -lGLU -lglut   -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/usr/local/cuda/SDK/C/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/SDK/C/common/lib -lcutil
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcutil
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [vfRay] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/antonio/vfray'
make: *** [cuda] Error 2
```

Comment: The option to specify import paths is `-I`, and `-L` for libraries.

Comment: Still ain't working, please read the edit. I believe this won't work until the makefile is modified.

Comment: Just modify the makefile with the `--compiler-bindir` options I provided in my answer. You are making this 10 times more complex than it needs to be. None of what you are asking about now has anything at all to do with your original question......

Comment: Nowhere in that makefile. The key line is the part you didn't post. See the edit below.

Comment: Dude, relax. I'm just doing what you tell me. The original question is "Trouble compiling CUDA code". You didn't provide the makefile mod that is needed. Look at the makefile in the question and tell me what should be written and where.

Answer (score 3):

The nvcc `--compiler-bindir`, as the name suggests, takes a directory as an argument, not the compiler executable itself. In order to use an alternative compiler in this way, you need to pass a directory which contains an either an executable called gcc, or a link called gcc which points to a valid version of gcc. The easiest way to do this is to create a locate directory containing a symbolic link to a supported compiler version. Something like this:

```
1.   user@cuda:~$ mkdir jdir

2.   user@cuda:~$ cd jdir

3.   user@cuda:~/jdir$ ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.4 ./gcc

4.   user@cuda:~$ ls -l jdir
     total 0
     lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 12 2011-08-31 08:34 gcc -> /usr/bin/gcc-4.4

5.   user@cuda:~/jdir$ cd ..

6.   user@cuda:~$ nvcc --compiler-bindir=./jdir -arch=sm_20 -c -Xptxas="-v" particles3.cu
     ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6pointsP6float4f' for 'sm_20'
     ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6pointsP6float4f
         0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
     ptxas info    : Used 29 registers, 44 bytes cmem[0], 4 bytes cmem[14], 12 bytes cmem[16]
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

In the code you are trying build you need to edit the file [common.mk, line 93](http://code.google.com/p/vfray/source/browse/trunk/common.mk#93) and change the `--compiler-bindir` option to an absolute path which you set up somewhere containing links in the way demonstrated above.

---

**EDIT 2:**

The code you are trying to compile is relying on the [NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK](http://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-sdk). You will have to either set an environment variable `ROOT_DIR` to point to the C tree inside the SDK distribution or modify [line 50](http://code.google.com/p/vfray/source/browse/trunk/common.mk#50) of the common.mk file that comes with the code you are trying to build. You will also have to ensure that the cutil library has been compiled by running make in the C/common directory of the SDK root.

Comment: I'm building through the makefiles in the project, not individually.

Comment: The .cu file I used is just one of my own for illustration purposes. The setup of the bindir only needs to be done once, and the solution will be exactly the same in a Makefile as performing the compilation individually.

Comment: Please see my edited question; I'm getting fatal error: cutil.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Please don't edit your *questions* into other people's answers!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Didn't notice.

Comment: I tried the -lpath/to/cutil and still got the same error. Can you point what's wrong? See the new edit.

Comment: I made your suggested mod on the makefil on the cuda: section and got the same error.

Comment: I made the mod in common.mk changing the gcc version to 4.4, now I'm getting the cutil file missing error. How can I modify that?